# Convert SQL query to sequelize query with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I've been at this for several days attempting to convert what I thought was a relatively simple SQL query into sequelize format.  I cannot seem to figure it out for the life of me.  I'm relatively new to sequelize, and my SQL skills can use some help as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Here is the SQL query I have (which works for what I'm attempting to do) which I'm struggling to get to work in sequelize:

```
    SELECT 
        book.id,
        book.author,
        book.title,
        book_type.type,
        book_sub_type.sub_type,
        book_location.location,
        book_language.language
    FROM book
    INNER JOIN book_type ON book.book_type_id = book_type.id
    INNER JOIN book_sub_type ON book.book_sub_type_id = book_sub_type.id
    INNER JOIN book_location ON book.book_location_id = book_location.id
    INNER JOIN book_language ON book.book_language_id = book_language.id
    WHERE
        book.author LIKE '%history%' OR
        book.title LIKE '%history%' OR
        book_type.type LIKE '%history%' OR
        book_sub_type.sub_type LIKE '%history%' OR
        book_language.language LIKE '%history%' OR
        book_location.location LIKE '%history%'
    ORDER BY book_type.type, book_sub_type.sub_type;
```

Here is as far as I have gotten (this sequelize query returns 0 results because it is searching for the substring "history" in all columns, instead of at least one column):

```
    const books = await Book.findAll({
        where: {
            [Op.or]: [
                {author: { [Op.substring]: 'history' }},
                {title: { [Op.substring]: 'history' }}
            ]
        },
        attributes: ['id', 'author', 'title'],
        include: [
            { 
                model: BookType, 
                attributes: ['type'], 
                where: {
                    type: { [Op.substring]: 'history' }
                } 
            },
            { 
                model: BookSubType, 
                attributes: ['sub_type'], 
                where: {
                    sub_type: { [Op.substring]: 'history' }
                } 
            },
            { 
                model: BookLanguage, 
                attributes: ['language'], 
                where: {
                    language: { [Op.substring]: 'history' }
                } 
            },
            { 
                model: BookLocation, 
                attributes: ['location'], 
                where: {
                    location: { [Op.substring]: 'history' }
                }  
            },
        ]
    });
```

My schema is as follows:

```
`book` table columns:
`id`, `author`, `title`, `book_type_id`, `book_sub_type_id`, 
`book_language_id`, `book_location_id`

`book_type` table columns:
`id`, `type`

`book_sub_type` table columns:
`id`, `sub_type`

`book_location` table columns:
`id`, `location`

`book_language` table columns:
`id`, `language`
```

In sequelize, I have the following relationships established:

```
    Book.belongsTo(BookType);
    Book.belongsTo(BookSubType);
    Book.belongsTo(BookLanguage);
    Book.belongsTo(BookLocation);
    BookType.hasMany(Book);
    BookSubType.hasMany(Book);
    BookLanguage.hasMany(Book);
    BookLocation.hasMany(Book);
```

The output should be 7 columns:
book.id, book.author, book.title, book_type.type, book_sub_type.sub_type, book_location.location, book_language.language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize build a SQL with a conditions in JOINs, so this is not good aproach. You should remove all `where` conditions from includes. There was a way in a sequelize <4.0.0 to write conditions to subquery using syntax

```
 where: {
      $or: [{
        '$book.sub_type$$': 'history'
      }, {
        '$book_type.type$': 'history'
      }]
 }
```

but I think this is not longer supported. Only way would be a custom query or use a sequelize literal in where object.

```
where: {
     [Op.or]: [{
         Sequelize.literal(`book_type.type LIKE ${history}`)
     }, {
         Sequelize.literal(`book_sub_type.sub_type LIKE ${history}`)
     }]
}
```

Keep in mind that with this approach there is a risk of SQL injection so you should validate an input or use some escape character strategy. Check [sequelize raw queries](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/raw-queries.html) and [seqeulize literal](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-literal)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was afraid I would have to use raw SQL to accomplish this.